# Printing the Guessed Letter

Tags: python

```
import random

title = ("Guess the Word Title")
print(title.center(80))

Tuple = ()
Tuple = ("Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter")

TupleItem = random.choice(Tuple)

Item_len = len(TupleItem)
ItemAsteriks = ("*" * Item_len)
print("\n\n\n", ItemAsteriks.center(80), "\n\n\n")

response = "n"

while response == "n":
    response = input("Would you like to guess the word (y / n)? ")
    if response == "y":
        break
    letter = input("\nEnter a letter: ")
    if letter.upper() in TupleItem.upper():
        print("The letter ", letter, "is in the word!\n")

        new_message = ""
        for i in range(len(TupleItem)):
            if TupleItem[i].upper()==letter.upper():
                new_message += TupleItem[i]
            else:
                new_message += ItemAsteriks[i]
        ItemAskeriks = new_message
    else:
        print("The letter ", letter, "is not in the word!\n")

GuessedWord = input("\nGuess the word then: ")

if GuessedWord.upper() == TupleItem.upper():
    print("You guessed the right word. Congratz!")
else:
    print("You guessed the wrong word. The right word was:", TupleItem)

input("\n\nPress Enter to Exit. ")
```

This is what i've come up so far. If the word is "Summer" and user guessed letter "U", I want to show/update the asterisks like: *u****., and so on. I tried some print commands under the for loop but i couldnt figure it out.

Comment: You simply need to print `ItemAsteriks` after you update it, just exactly as you did at the start of the program.  You didn't show any attempt to do this, so it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: please use python naming convention. don't use PascalCase for variable names

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the problem is that it will always just show the most recent letter, but not the ones from before. I would initialise a list of strings, one for each letter in the word, starting with

`guessed = ["*"] * len(TupleItem)`

Then at each guess, iterate though the real word and replace `*` entries with the actual guessed letter.

```
for k, ch in enumerate(TupleItem.upper()):
    if ch == letter.upper():
        guessed[k] = ch
```

Then you can simply

`print("".join(guessed))`